# FireFox vs Chrome CSS div wrap error

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, firefox

```js
function multiplyNode(node, count, deep) {
    for (var i = 0, copy; i < count - 1; i++) {
        copy = node.cloneNode(deep);
        node.parentNode.insertBefore(copy, node);
    }
}
multiplyNode(document.querySelector("#divp1"), 5, true);
multiplyNode(document.querySelector("#divp2"), 5, true);
multiplyNode(document.querySelector("#divp3"), 5, true);
multiplyNode(document.querySelector("#divp4"), 5, true);
multiplyNode(document.querySelector("#divp5"), 5, true);
multiplyNode(document.querySelector("#divp6"), 5, true);
multiplyNode(document.querySelector("#divp7"), 5, true);
multiplyNode(document.querySelector("#divp8"), 5, true);
multiplyNode(document.querySelector("#divp9"), 5, true);
multiplyNode(document.querySelector("#divp10"), 5, true);

multiplyNode(document.querySelector("#divg1"), 5, true);
multiplyNode(document.querySelector("#divg2"), 5, true);
multiplyNode(document.querySelector("#divg3"), 5, true);
multiplyNode(document.querySelector("#divg4"), 5, true);
multiplyNode(document.querySelector("#divg5"), 5, true);
multiplyNode(document.querySelector("#divg6"), 5, true);
multiplyNode(document.querySelector("#divg7"), 5, true);
multiplyNode(document.querySelector("#divg8"), 5, true);
multiplyNode(document.querySelector("#divg9"), 5, true);
multiplyNode(document.querySelector("#divg10"), 5, true);

multiplyNode(document.querySelector("#divn1"), 63, true);
multiplyNode(document.querySelector("#divn2"), 63, true);
```

```css
#bin1 {
  width: 960px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
#divNA {
    width: 100%;
    height: 13px;
    padding: 1px;
    float: left
}
#divNA2 {
    height: 13px;
    width: 13px;
    padding: 1px;
    float: left
}
#divn1 {
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
    float: left
}
#divn2 {
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
    float: left
}
#divg1 {
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaff;
    float: left
}
#divg2 {
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaff;
    float: left
}
#divg3 {
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaff;
    float: left
}
#divg4 {
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaff;
    float: left
}
#divg5 {
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaff;
    float: left
}
#divg6 {
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaff;
    float: left
}
#divg7 {
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaff;
    float: left
}
#divg8 {
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaff;
    float: left
}
#divg9 {
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaff;
    float: left
}
#divg10 {
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaff;
    float: left
}
#divp1 {
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    border: 1px solid #ffaaaa;
    float: left
}
#divp2 {
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    border: 1px solid #ffaaaa;
    float: left
}
#divp3 {
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    border: 1px solid #ffaaaa;
    float: left
}
#divp4 {
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    border: 1px solid #ffaaaa;
    float: left
}
#divp5 {
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    border: 1px solid #ffaaaa;
    float: left
}
#divp6 {
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    border: 1px solid #ffaaaa;
    float: left
}
#divp7 {
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    border: 1px solid #ffaaaa;
    float: left
}
#divp8 {
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    border: 1px solid #ffaaaa;
    float: left
}
#divp9 {
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    border: 1px solid #ffaaaa;
    float: left
}
#divp10 {
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    border: 1px solid #ffaaaa;
    float: left
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="bin1">

    <div id="divNA2"></div>
    <div id="divNA2">A</div>
    <div id="divNA2"></div>
    <div id="divp1"></div>
    <div id="divNA2"></div>
    <div id="divp2"></div>
    <div id="divNA2"></div>
    <div id="divp3"></div>
    <div id="divNA2"></div>
    <div id="divp4"></div>
    <div id="divNA2"></div>
    <div id="divp5"></div>
    <div id="divNA2"></div>
    <div id="divNA2"></div>
    <div id="divp6"></div>
    <div id="divNA2"></div>
    <div id="divp7"></div>
    <div id="divNA2"></div>
    <div id="divp8"></div>
    <div id="divNA2"></div>
    <div id="divp9"></div>
    <div id="divNA2"></div>
    <div id="divp10"></div>
    <div id="divNA2"></div>

    <div id="divNA2"></div>
    <div id="divNA2">B</div>
    <div id="divNA2"></div>
    <div id="divg1"></div>
    <div id="divNA2"></div>
    <div id="divg2"></div>
    <div id="divNA2"></div>
    <div id="divg3"></div>
    <div id="divNA2"></div>
    <div id="divg4"></div>
    <div id="divNA2"></div>
    <div id="divg5"></div>
    <div id="divNA2"></div>
    <div id="divNA2"></div>
    <div id="divg6"></div>
    <div id="divNA2"></div>
    <div id="divg7"></div>
    <div id="divNA2"></div>
    <div id="divg8"></div>
    <div id="divNA2"></div>
    <div id="divg9"></div>
    <div id="divNA2"></div>
    <div id="divg10"></div>
    <div id="divNA"></div>

    <div id="divNA2">C</div>
    <div id="divn1"></div>

    <div id="divNA2">D</div>
    <div id="divn2"></div>
</div>
```

I am trying to get a bunch of square DIVs to fit into a larger rectangular DIV. It is important they wrap on to the next line at a specific DIV. The problem is that FireFox seems to give a bit more room before wrapping than Chrome.

This can be seen in its intended state on Chrome:
[image: Chrome DIV display]
And its current state on FireFox:
[image: Chrome DIV display]
*(The images are snipped with different padding but the boxes are really the same size)*

The code used is identical for both images and is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style id="css">
#bin1 {
  width: 960px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
#divNA {
    width: 100%;
    height: 13px;
    padding: 1px;
    float: left
}
#divNA2 {
    height: 13px;
    width: 13px;
    padding: 1px;
    float: left
}
#divn1 {
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
    float: left
}
#divn2 {
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
    float: left
}
#divg1 {
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaff;
    float: left
}
#divg2 {
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaff;
    float: left
}
#divg3 {
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaff;
    float: left
}
#divg4 {
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaff;
    float: left
}
#divg5 {
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaff;
    float: left
}
#divg6 {
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaff;
    float: left
}
#divg7 {
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaff;
    float: left
}
#divg8 {
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaff;
    float: left
}
#divg9 {
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaff;
    float: left
}
#divg10 {
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaff;
    float: left
}
#divp1 {
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    border: 1px solid #ffaaaa;
    float: left
}
#divp2 {
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    border: 1px solid #ffaaaa;
    float: left
}
#divp3 {
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    border: 1px solid #ffaaaa;
    float: left
}
#divp4 {
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    border: 1px solid #ffaaaa;
    float: left
}
#divp5 {
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    border: 1px solid #ffaaaa;
    float: left
}
#divp6 {
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    border: 1px solid #ffaaaa;
    float: left
}
#divp7 {
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    border: 1px solid #ffaaaa;
    float: left
}
#divp8 {
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    border: 1px solid #ffaaaa;
    float: left
}
#divp9 {
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    border: 1px solid #ffaaaa;
    float: left
}
#divp10 {
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    border: 1px solid #ffaaaa;
    float: left
}
</style>

<div id="bin1">

    <div id="divNA2"></div>
    <div id="divNA2">A</div>
    <div id="divNA2"></div>
    <div id="divp1"></div>
    <div id="divNA2"></div>
    <div id="divp2"></div>
    <div id="divNA2"></div>
    <div id="divp3"></div>
    <div id="divNA2"></div>
    <div id="divp4"></div>
    <div id="divNA2"></div>
    <div id="divp5"></div>
    <div id="divNA2"></div>
    <div id="divNA2"></div>
    <div id="divp6"></div>
    <div id="divNA2"></div>
    <div id="divp7"></div>
    <div id="divNA2"></div>
    <div id="divp8"></div>
    <div id="divNA2"></div>
    <div id="divp9"></div>
    <div id="divNA2"></div>
    <div id="divp10"></div>
    <div id="divNA2"></div>

    <div id="divNA2"></div>
    <div id="divNA2">B</div>
    <div id="divNA2"></div>
    <div id="divg1"></div>
    <div id="divNA2"></div>
    <div id="divg2"></div>
    <div id="divNA2"></div>
    <div id="divg3"></div>
    <div id="divNA2"></div>
    <div id="divg4"></div>
    <div id="divNA2"></div>
    <div id="divg5"></div>
    <div id="divNA2"></div>
    <div id="divNA2"></div>
    <div id="divg6"></div>
    <div id="divNA2"></div>
    <div id="divg7"></div>
    <div id="divNA2"></div>
    <div id="divg8"></div>
    <div id="divNA2"></div>
    <div id="divg9"></div>
    <div id="divNA2"></div>
    <div id="divg10"></div>
    <div id="divNA"></div>

    <div id="divNA2">C</div>
    <div id="divn1"></div>

    <div id="divNA2">D</div>
    <div id="divn2"></div>
</div>

<script id="javascript">
function multiplyNode(node, count, deep) {
    for (var i = 0, copy; i < count - 1; i++) {
        copy = node.cloneNode(deep);
        node.parentNode.insertBefore(copy, node);
    }
}
multiplyNode(document.querySelector("#divp1"), 5, true);
multiplyNode(document.querySelector("#divp2"), 5, true);
multiplyNode(document.querySelector("#divp3"), 5, true);
multiplyNode(document.querySelector("#divp4"), 5, true);
multiplyNode(document.querySelector("#divp5"), 5, true);
multiplyNode(document.querySelector("#divp6"), 5, true);
multiplyNode(document.querySelector("#divp7"), 5, true);
multiplyNode(document.querySelector("#divp8"), 5, true);
multiplyNode(document.querySelector("#divp9"), 5, true);
multiplyNode(document.querySelector("#divp10"), 5, true);

multiplyNode(document.querySelector("#divg1"), 5, true);
multiplyNode(document.querySelector("#divg2"), 5, true);
multiplyNode(document.querySelector("#divg3"), 5, true);
multiplyNode(document.querySelector("#divg4"), 5, true);
multiplyNode(document.querySelector("#divg5"), 5, true);
multiplyNode(document.querySelector("#divg6"), 5, true);
multiplyNode(document.querySelector("#divg7"), 5, true);
multiplyNode(document.querySelector("#divg8"), 5, true);
multiplyNode(document.querySelector("#divg9"), 5, true);
multiplyNode(document.querySelector("#divg10"), 5, true);

multiplyNode(document.querySelector("#divn1"), 63, true);
multiplyNode(document.querySelector("#divn2"), 63, true);
</script>
```

JSbin link [here](http://jsbin.com/dekucopoku/1/edit?html,css,js,output).

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I cannot figure out the root of this inconsistency.

Comment: did u try `display:inline-block;`

Comment: I'm actually a little confused here. Your JSBin link looks the same on Chrome and FF on my side, even after moving it to [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8wh2hqpu/). [Here's a screenie from FF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6tMI.png)

Comment: @Frits JSbin uses it's own interpreter so it will be consistent on any browser in any set resolution. It makes it great for consistent code sharing but not great for distinguishing between browsers. Whenwed as a plain HTML file outside of JSbin it should look 'as intended by the browser'.